# add onChange to input in string in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm using react for my project and I have the string below.

```
const text= "<p><strong>Late 19th Century</strong></p><ul><li>in Yellowstone Park, every type of <input type="text" /> was prohibitedas</li></ul>"
```

and I use :

```
 <div  dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: text }}></div>
```

how to handle onChange input when I use dangerouslySetInnerHTML on string in react.

Comment: Why are you injecting the HTML like this and not just using JSX? I don't see anything specific that would preclude you from listing the HTML elements in a JSX block.

Comment: I get it from API that was created with a rich text editor.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

At this point you're working with native HTML, it is no longer React and you cannot treat it as such. You'll either have to go down the rabbit trail of manually attaching event listeners to the set HTML or just use React as it's intended.

**NOTE:** I'm assuming you have a good reason to do this. Otherwise, **I do not** recommend this for normal use-cases in React.

That said, here is a way you could still use the string of HTML with React's state.

For simplicity I added an `id` attribute to the `input` in your string. Also note that, because of the difference in when the native DOM change event fires vs the React change event, you have to click out of the input to see the new value.

```js
const {useState, useEffect} = React;

const text= '<p><strong>Late 19th Century</strong></p><ul><li>in Yellowstone Park, every type of <input id="myText" type="text" /> was prohibitedas</li></ul>'

const Example = () => {
  const [value, setValue] = useState('');
  
  useEffect(() => {
    const el = document.getElementById('myText');
    
    el.addEventListener('change', (e) => setValue(e.target.value));
  }, []);
  
  console.log('value', value);
   
  return <div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: text }}></div>;
}

ReactDOM.render(<Example />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.8.4/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.8.4/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Adding to the Brian's answer above, you can add listener on 'input' like

```
const el = document.getElementById('myText');
el.addEventListener('input');
```

to see the new value similar to react's onChange.